How can any supremum of a proper subset of the real numbers be outside the set, following the logic below?
Let E ⊂ R, E is bounded above, and α = sup E. Then ∀ε > 0, there exists some t ∈ E such that
α − ε < t ⇒ α − t < ε
Since α > t, α − t = |α − t|. It follows that
|α − t| < ε
which implies α = t ∈ E.
Why is this wrong?

You are simply showing that for that specific $\varepsilon$ then there is some $t\in E$ such that $\alpha-\varepsilon < t$. For example, take (0,1). Then $\alpha=1$. Then for $\varepsilon_1 = 1/2$, $\alpha-\varepsilon_1 < 4/5$. For $\varepsilon_2 = 1/3$, $\alpha-\varepsilon_2 < 6/7$ and so on.

For every $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $t\in E$ such that $\alpha<t+\epsilon$.
It means that for every fixed $\epsilon>0$, we can find an element $t$ satisfying the above condition. If you change the value of $\epsilon$, $t$ will also change.
